# How to determine the value of a variable in a matrix to make it linearly independent of two other given matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am given matrices:

\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ \:1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ a\:&-2\end{pmatrix}

and asked to determine the value of $a$ such that the above matrices are *linearly independent*. I know how to work with vectors: put them together into a matrix and use row reduction, if no free columns then the vectors are linearly independent. But how to do this with matrices? Thank you.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean. Do you mean that you want $a$ such that $xA+yB=C$, where $x$ and $y$ are scalars and $A$, $B$ and $C$ correspond to your matrices?
If that is the case, then for every $a$ there is no $x$ and $y$ such that the equality $xA+yB=C$ holds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is the same as asking

> For which $a$ will $x,y,z=0$ be the only solutions to the equation $$x\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\ \:0&1\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ \:1&0\end{pmatrix}+z\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ \:a&-2\end{pmatrix}=0 \,?$$

Looking at the top-right entry, $x$ must be zero already. Then looking at the bottom-right entry, $z$ must be zero. So $y$ is zero too, and we did all this without even considering $a$, so $a$ can be anything.

Answer (score 4):

You can consider the matrix:

$$
A=\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&2&0&1\\
1&0&1&0\\
1&0&a&-2\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and because $A$ is of size $3\times4$, then

$$ A \quad\text{is of full rank} \quad \text{if and only if}\ \ \det(AA^{t})\neq 0. $$

Comment: Can $a$ be any number then?

Comment: Any number $a$ such that $\det(AA^{t})\neq 0$ when you work in $\mathbb{R}$. When you work in $\mathbb{C}$ you consider $\det(AA^{*})\neq 0$.

Comment: I don't know what C is, working in R so any will do. Thank you very much!